# Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data

there are few answers to the question already. But none of them works for me.

I can't figure it out for the life of me why the error is coming.

Following are the approaches I tried:

- using AbstractMongoConfiguration
- Manually registering the mongoTemplate bean with ApplicationContext

Whenever I try to run my test during maven build or while deploying on tomcat error below comes up

Here is the configuration.

```
package com.fordit.project.config;

@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.company.project")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.company.project")
public class ProjectConfiguration {

@Value("${project.db.driver_class}")
private String driverClassname;

@Value("${project.db.connection_string}")
private String connectionString;

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws PropertyVetoException {
    Properties mysqlProperties = new Properties();
    mysqlProperties.setProperty("characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
    mysqlProperties.setProperty("useUnicode", "true");

    ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
    cpds.setProperties(mysqlProperties);
    cpds.setDriverClass(driverClassname);
    cpds.setJdbcUrl(connectionString);
    cpds.setAcquireIncrement(2);
    return cpds;
}

@Bean
public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer getPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer() throws IOException {
    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    ResourceLoader resourceLoader = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
    ppc.setLocations(
            resourceLoader.getResource(System.getProperty("PROJECT_CONFIGURATION_FILE")));
    return ppc;
}

@Bean
public static RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {

    String roleHierarchyStringRepresentation
            = Role.ROLE_ADMIN + " > " + Role.ROLE_FIRM + "\n"
            + Role.ROLE_FIRM + " = " + Role.ROLE_LAWYER+ "= "+Role.ROLE_USER;

    //logger.info("Registered Role Hierarchy: \n{}", roleHierarchyStringRepresentation);
    RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
    roleHierarchy.setHierarchy(roleHierarchyStringRepresentation);
    return roleHierarchy;
}
}
```

Mongo Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.company.project")
@Profile("container")
public class MongoDBConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

@Value("${project.mongodb.hostname}")
private String host;

@Value("${project.mongodb.port}")
private Integer port;

@Value("${project.mongodb.name}")
private String db;

@Value("${project.mongodb.username}")
private String username;

@Value("${project.mongodb.password}")
private String password;

@Value("${project.mongodb.authenticationDB}")
private String authDB;

@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate()
    throws UnknownHostException, java.net.UnknownHostException {
return new MongoTemplate(
        new SimpleMongoDbFactory(
                    mongoClient(),
                    getDatabaseName()
            )
    );
}

@Override
@Bean
public MongoClient mongoClient()  {
    MongoClient mongoClient = null;
    try {
        mongoClient = new MongoClient(
                new ServerAddress(host, port),
                Collections.singletonList(
                        MongoCredential.createMongoCRCredential(
                                username,
                                authDB,
                                password.toCharArray()
                        )
                )
        );
    } catch (java.net.UnknownHostException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MongoDBConfiguration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return mongoClient;
}

@Override
protected String getDatabaseName() {
    return db;
}
```

}

Error log:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'forumDAL' defined in file [/home/ashay/projects/kuber/target/classes/com/fordit/kuber/forum/ForumDAL.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'forumRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'mongoTemplate' available
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:192)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:107)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:243)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
... 26 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `Profile("container")` in `MongoDBConfiguration`.

Explanation:  Because the `@Profile` is there, that means that that class will not be instantiated by Spring unless you are running Spring with that profile.  My guess is that you are not setting `spring.profiles.active` property to "container" when you run your application via Tomcat or during your integration testing.

If you want to leave the `@Profile("container")` there then just make sure you set the profile to "container".  There are multiple ways to do this.  One quick easy way is to use Java system properties, e.g. `-Dspring.profiles.active=container`, when you execute your integration tests or run your application in Tomcat.

Comment: It worked.thanks. can you elaborate why it worked? I have not fully understood

Comment: Added an explanation.

Comment: Saved me! explanation makes sense since it worked locally for me but not in out prod env.